# What aren't user handles in comment replies working?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comment-replies

The last few days, when I try to comment, I notice the user handles aren't *quite* recognized in comment replies. I'll type is @Somebody, and the little popup appears that I can hit tab and auto-complete, or click on, but the handle isn't linked to the user account. I've not been getting notifications with people tag me, and I've see this happen to other people.

(If this isn't the appropriate forum, where is?)

**Examples:**

Example #1: As can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105971/c-why-does-error-no-matching-function-appear-when-it-100-looks-like-they-ma?noredirect=1#comment61753982_37105971), I've entered the handle but it isn't linked to the account.

[image]

Example #2: some one else tagged me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083308/lambda-functions-c-does-capturing-the-index-of-a-loop-make-a-difference/37083488#37083488), but it isn't linked to my account and I didn't receive a notification.

[image]

Comment: Kinda obvious, T.C. is not a name.  Just a nick of somebody that doesn't like to get comment notifications.

Comment: The second example is somewhat redundant.  A comment is being left on your Answer, and you would get a notification regardless of whether the `@` user handle/nym is used.  I believe what happened was you got a visible notification of the next comment that was left on your Answer, and this overwrites the previous ones at the top of the list.  This is the behavior I observe both in the browser (mobile and desktop) and in the StackExchange app.  In other words the queue linked by the "inbox" icon near the top of this page will only notify you of the most recent comment on your Answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't linked to account"?

Comment: Don't handles hyperlink to accounts? They aren't just supposed to be a text field with fancy auto complete, are they? @TZHX ... I just tried it... Is it only certain types of comments do this?

Comment: No. They are just a text field. They don't hyperlink to accounts unless you manually build it into a link with mark down. This isn't Twitter.

Comment: Well I feel stupid now - I could have sworn it was linking... Perception vs reality - reality wins.

Comment: All this stuff about linking has muddled the real problem, that the OP is not getting notifications when being tagged in comments. Does this happen a lot? PS you wrote "If this isn't the appropriate forum, where is?" And, well, this IS the appropriate site. But it is not a forum!

Comment: In the second example, you should have been notified just for the fact the comment is for a question you asked. The user doesn't even need to @-refer your username.